# Past participle form of "break-even"

Tags: past-participles

*Break even* is commonly used in economics to refer to the point where cost and revenue are equal. However, instead of using the long way of saying that

> Firm X had reached the point of break even

is it possible to say

> Firm X had broken even?

I realise that *broke even* is in common usage today, but somehow *broken even* just doesn't sound right. Is it correct or is there a better way of saying it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, but you don't need the hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply say *"Firm X broke even."* It would mean the same thing.

Comment: +1. I would definitely say something like "I broke even last year," or "the goal is to at least break even."

Comment: -1: Past perfect doesn't really "mean the same thing" as simple past tense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Can you please explain how in this instance they mean something different?

Comment: There's nothing special about the compound verb *to break even* making it unsuitable for past perfect. *"Firm X had broken even for three years before it reported a small profit last year"*, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't say that I think the past perfect is unsuitable, I just think the simple past is more concise in this instance. For the OP's shorter sentence with no timeframe given, do you think that "Firm X had broken even." differs in meaning from the sentence "Firm X broke even."? (I sincerely want to know this. And I also sincerely appreciate you explaining your vote.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple past: I broke even last year. No connection to present.
Present perfect: I have broken even. Past but still has connection to present
Past perfect: I had broken even until the crash in ... Completed before a time in the past.